# How to create a custom aspx page in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I want to create/customize the Umbraco framework. For that I need to create a new aspx page in the Umbraco folder and customize the database table fields. Any one have an idea on how to create custom pages in the Umbraco Framework?

Answer (score 5):

There are quite a few approaches to your question,
The simplest answer would be to create a folder called pages, then in your web.config simply add the folder under the key "**umbracoReservedPaths**" this will tell umbraco's url writer to ignore any page that is found under the pages folder.

The other approach is the more "clean" one, you could simply just create a usercontrol to customize the database fields and insert the usercontrol onto a page via a macro.

some good reference points are:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/4047-Using-my-own-aspx-pages-in-Umbraco

http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/introduction-to-umbraco/developer-introduction/using-net-user-controls.aspx